# facebook page id

Tags: php, sdk, facebook-page

How to get facebook fan page id by using php sdk? Currently, I'm using php sdk and I can retrieve user information but I can't retrieve the fan page information. Please help me to explain.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could lookup the URL to retrieve the ID...

https://graph.facebook.com/?id=http://www.facebook.com/cocacola

Comment: I means I already log in and I want to retrieve my own fan page information.

Comment: You can do that on an PHP server without access token?